# MySQL query to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm switching from MySQL to PDO and I'm unsure if this query is correct.. would I still be required to write the if command.

```
public function User_Login($_iUsername,$_iPassword) {
    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($_iUsername);
    $password=mysql_real_escape_string($password);
    $md5_password=md5($_iPassword);
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT _iD FROM users WHERE _iUsername='$_iUsername' and _iPassword='$md5_password' AND _iStatus='1'");
    if( mysql_num_rows( $query ) == 1 ) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query );
        return $row['_iD'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

TO

```
public function User_Login($_iUsername,$_iPassword) {
    $md5_password = md5($_iPassword);
    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT _iD FROM users WHERE _iUsername='$_iUsername' and _iPassword='$md5_password' AND _iStatus='1'");
    $sth->execute();

    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you're not properly parameterizing the query.  It's great that you're using PDO, but one of the main purposes of the change is the ability to parameterize queries.  Secondly, `md5` is a very weak hash.  I suggest using bcrypt instead.  Finally, `PDOStatement::rowCount` is the method you are looking for.

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT _ID FROM users WHERE _iUsername = ?
    AND _iPassword = ? AND _iStatus = 1");
$sth->execute(array($_iUsername, $md5_password));
if ($sth->rowCount() == 1) {
    $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $row['_iD'];
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Parameterizing a query is advantageous because it prevents SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I agree with Explosion Pills, but I thought I'd post a small suggestion - if you're expecting only a single row with a single value, I don't understand why do you try to fetch an array and then parse it. Simply use `fetchColumn()`.

Comment: `execute`s parameter should be an array. `numRows` should be `rowCount`, there's no such constant called `FETCH_ARRAY`.

Comment: @JordanDoyle already corrected the others, but updated `FETCH_ARRAY`

Comment: Thank you for the replies guys, what is the question mark next to WHERE " WHERE _iUsername = ? " what the meaning of it.

Comment: Found it, I appreciate the answer! Really helped!

Comment: @ExplosionPills Pills I never forget that.